# how add comment at end of text not numbers in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I understand for numbers you can use the `n()` function because if you do `+n("comment")` to a number it doesn't change the number.

What about string text? I can't use `+n()` and add a number to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you refer to:

- **`=IF(A1="hello"; 10; 20)+N("add comment")`** **works**
- **`=IF(A1="hello"; "x"; "y")+N("add comment")`** **not working**

for appending a hidden comment to text values you can do:

- **`=IFERROR(IF(A1="hello"; "x"; "y");"add comment")`**

use it with wisdom